# WPF - Accessing GDPicture object in a viewmodel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel, dependency-properties

I am using MVVM and somehow I should have access to  GDpicture object in my viewmodel.
here is the XAML

```
 <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="WindowsFormsHost1"   Height="991" Width="1583">
        <gdpicture:GdViewer x:Name="m_GDViewer"                                
                            BackColor="White" Margin="5,5,5,5" DisplayQuality="DisplayQualityBicubicHQ" 
                            DocumentAlignment="DocumentAlignmentMiddleCenter"
                            DocumentPosition="DocumentPositionMiddleCenter" 
                            MouseButtonForMouseMode="MouseButtonLeft" 
                            MouseWheelMode="MouseWheelModeZoom" RectBorderSize="1"  RectIsEditable="True" ZoomMode="ZoomModeFitToViewer" ZoomStep="25" />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
```

What kind of Binding should I use to get the GDViewer object in my view model? (I am trying to use m_GDViewer.DisplayFromFile(filename). but m_GDViewer is not accessible in viewmodel. But I can access it only from xaml code behind).

Comment: winforms doesn't support MVVM. what kind of thing is GDViewer?

Comment: GDPicture.NET. I created WPF application and Embedded GDpicture. I need to use this in my viewmodel. But I dont see any dependency property for it.

Comment: Again, winforms is a piece of crap, therefore it does not support MVVM. It does not have any `DependencyProperties` to bind to / from. It's a crappy dinosaur. You will have to break MVVM and write dirty code